# Coded UI Test Windows application on Build Server in TFS

Tags: tfs, automation, azure-devops, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I have developed a window/desktop application. I have already deployed this application on Build Server. I have developed coded ui test cases to perform automated testing on build server in continuous integrated environment. I would like to know, when i queue build nad build execute, how coded ui will launch application under tests (which is desktop application) and will execute all tests?

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to run coded UI tests from TFS/VSTS? Are you able to run the coded ui tests manually on build server now?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how to run coded UI tests from TFS/VSTS.

Firstly, you need to run your agent as an [interactive process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#account). Regarding how to deploy an agent on windows, please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).

Secondly, add your coded UI tests project into TFS version control.

Last, create a build definition to use [Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) task and [Run Functional Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/run-functional-tests) task to run the tests.